# Differentiate method used to open an Android app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, push-notification

I am working with push notifications in Android and am using NotificationBuilder and PendingIntent to attach a content intent to the notification.  This all works fine and well, but the client wants the intent to trigger only if the banner is clicked.  What seems to be happening is that, with a banner active, even clicking the app from launcher is executing the pending intent.

I've spent a good amount of time trying to find ways to differentiate the methods of the app opening, but is there a way to disable the intents from launcher while allowing it to trigger from clicking the banner?

Comment: Clicking the app from the launcher should always open the app. This is inherently different from opening the app from a notification in the notifications panel, so the launcher click should not be executing the same exact PendingIntent that you have set for the notification (in fact, I don't think launchers use PendingIntents for that, they just get a launch intent from the PackageManager for the target app). Can you show us something to prove that you get launched by the same Intent for both cases? If not, just put some extras or change something about the notification intent and you're done.

Comment: Sometimes that is all it takes.  The intent was not firing, but giving the impression of firing since the activity it opened uses a static context - the state of the context used while building the PendingIntent was held over to the save activity that was launched.